# how to avoid overlapping when using position : fixed

Tags: html, css

Here is the current state of my project:

[image: web application]

And on the left you see a sub menu with the next

```scss
:host {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $color-blue-100;
  width: 14rem;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  border-left: solid 1px;

//Doesn't matter below
  h1 {
    font-size: 23px !important;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 4rem;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    background: $color-orange-100;
    display: flex;

    label {
      margin: auto 0 auto 2rem;
    }
  }
```

And to the right I have 3 components written in angular and before them i'm inserting sub menu

```html
<dash-admin-menu></dash-admin-menu>
<div class="vsk__column">
  <dash-create-activity></dash-create-activity>
  <dash-create-partner></dash-create-partner>
  <dash-create-resort></dash-create-resort>
</div>
```

```scss
 .#{css-namespace}column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  
}
```

The problem is that i want my sub menu to be fixed but if I do so I'm overlapping my three components.
[overlapped picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Orv.png)
How can I avoid this ?

Comment: I forgot to indicate photo when i put position:fixed in the css
```:host {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $color-blue-100;
  width: 14rem;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  border-left: solid 1px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about setting a left margin on ".vsk_column" with the size equals to the width of the menu ?

You could use a variable in css

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to prevent the menu to be moved when scrolling on the right side? Maybe better not do set position:fixed on the left menu. Set it to height:100vh; and .vsk__column {overflow: auto;}

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative (quite simple workaround), you can try to set the height of the dash-admin-menu and then offsetting the vsk__column div by the same amount of pixels (e.g. 100px), like in following:

```
<div class="admin_menu_wrapper>
  <dash-admin-menu></dash-admin-menu>
</div>
<div class="vsk__column">
  <dash-create-activity></dash-create-activity>
  <dash-create-partner></dash-create-partner>
  <dash-create-resort></dash-create-resort>
</div>
```

and then in CSS something like this:

```
.admin_menu_wrapper {
 height: 100px;
}

.vsk__column {
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```